# PKI and SharePoint 2013

Tags: certificate

An Infrastructure admin I work with is in the process of gathering requirements for setting up a PKI on our internal domain and reached out to me asking if I had any requirements for PKI, specifically he was interested in any do not do this with regards to Key length, encryption types, cert types.

Haven't found much on the topic so I am assuming that there isn't anything really critical that stands out...am I correct in assuming this for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to stir up this answer on the TechNet forums by Trevor Seward incase there is anyone else looking for info on the topic. I took it as an answer.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/d8524a74-bff9-41e9-9dd1-964375e35fe6